# Mysterious visits to privileged URLs from anonymous user/bot

Tags: web-crawlers, logging

I maintain a Rails app. Every page except login and "forgot password" requires user authentication. Yesterday I noticed entries like this one in the access logs:

```
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:19:09:53 +0000] "GET /compendia HTTP/1.1" 302 120 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:19:09:53 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 927 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:19:10:37 +0000] "GET /noumena/428 HTTP/1.1" 302 120 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:19:10:37 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 928 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:19:15:11 +0000] "GET /data_ranges/1208/edit HTTP/1.1" 302 120 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:19:15:11 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 926 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:20:22:01 +0000] "GET /fields/392 HTTP/1.1" 302 120 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:20:22:01 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 926 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
54.209.60.63 - - [03/Nov/2015:21:55:29 +0000] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 1477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"
```

Each of the requests was properly redirected back to the login page. Still, those URLs would be valid for authenticated users. And anonymous users could not be able to know those URLs.

Is there some legitimate use case here? Or is one of my users compromised, and somehow they are leaking URLs but not credentials?

Comment: Users regularly bookmark and/or try to access pages that require authentication first. This isn't unusual at all.

Comment: Look for a pattern if you can find one. For example, are these in link order as they appear in your HTML? Could these all be typical user book-marked pages that may have been scraped from a browser via some JS or virus? Spammers and scrapers will create user accounts only later to come back. They often create a few at a time. Is there any indication that user accounts have been created and then abandoned? John is right, however, without a larger sample, I cannot tell you how suspicious this is but it looks suspicious to me so far. I am not sure we would really know without more evidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you displaying ads on your site from Amobee (formerly known as Kontera)?

The PTR record for this IP is `nat.aws.kontera.com`, suggesting that it is a crawler looking for your page's content in order to determine what ads may be relevant to that URL.

If you've loaded the Kontera JavaScript on login-protected pages, then you will find that they are crawled any time a logged-in user visits those pages. Try removing the JavaScript call from protected pages, and see if the crawling of those pages stops.

It's also possible that code has been added to the web page by a man in the middle attack before it reached the user who actually visited your site. Such an attack might have been launched by a network operator or malicious party in order to gain revenue from your content, or for other reasons.

This is one of many reasons that [every web site should run on HTTPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/96238/17007).

Comment: Interesting. I am not. But maybe Amobee (or some other company) installed ad injection software ... and the ads are coming from Amobee? I can see one of my users accidentally installing something like that...

Comment: [This AMA](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9120593#9125011) suggests that Amobee has a "network appliance":

"There is (sic) also companies like rgnets (http://rgnets.com/), amobee (http://www.amobee.com/) and FrontPorch (http://www.frontporch.com/), which offers network appliance that performs the HTTP interception and tampering. In this method there is no need to install anything on the user, all you need him to do is connect your network. Large public networks (hotles, events, airports, etc) are using it as well as some ISPs."

Comment: Update your answer to include the possibility of injection at airports-or-whatever and I'll accept it as the answer. I can see a user going to an airport and accidentally leaking some URLs. We aren't seeing this on our HTTPS site, so that lines up as well (since, presumably, you couldn't inject into HTTPS.) I hadn't thought of this as a reason to promote HTTPS but wow.

Comment: @MustModify Oh, that's nasty. I'd completely forgotten about the possibility of a malicious attack on the user. Updated.

Comment: I've noticed the same user agent string on my domain. Our users are all coming from mobile phones, so it got me thinking how Kontera is discovering the URLs. Based on this analysis, I believe it is because of shady browser extensions installed by the users. https://adguard.com/en/blog/big-star-labs-spyware/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be concerned about with this as it commonly shows up with secured applications on the internet. A user accesses a link through their bookmarks bar or through their browser history to go back to a page that they want to go back to and because their session has expired they are redirected to the login page to login first. No worries here.

**Update #1**
Further investigations into the IP in question have shown the following points...

- The IP adress has been detected through project honeypot but was classed as possibly a harmless web crawler as none of the IP's visits have caused any problems.
  http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_54.209.60.63
- Some users on the AbuseIP database report that removing the Web of Trust has resulted in the connections stopping however this can not be verified as the connections are being made against web servers not web browsers and WoT uses human ratings to rate websites.
  https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/54.209.60.63
  https://www.mywot.com/en/support/how-wot-works
- The IP has been listed on the BadIP's website as a malicious website as March 2015.
  https://www.badips.com/info/54.209.60.63

Based on the fact that none of these abuse reports about the IP address 54.209.60.63 actually state that anything malicious was done to the web server and even Project Honeypot confirms it is a possible web crawler and not a malicious machine there should be no concern.

The IP address has also since been de-activated from the offending account with Amazon and is no longer assigned to the original EC2 instance in question so there should be no further issues from this IP address regardless.

Comment: I'm not convinced. You're saying a user had bookmarked the URL on line 1, was redirected to login, waited a minute, then used a bookmark for the URL in line 3, then didn't login again, waited 5 minutes, tried another bookmark which also didn't work, then an hour later tried a fourth bookmark, and still didn't login?

Comment: Okay further digging into that particular IP address shows that it is known to do this same thing, no malicious actions have been taken by the IP. General consensus from what I can see is that this is some sort of crawling activity being done.

Comment: Put that as an answer and maybe provide some citations and I'll accept it... though obviously it's not very satisfying in terms of what's actually happening. Like, how is it getting those privileged URLs?